# Python wait for processes in multiprocessing Pool to complete without either closing Pool or use map()

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a code piece like below

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
for i in range(300):
    for m in range(500):
        data = do_some_calculation(resource)
        pool.apply_async(paralized_func, data, call_back=update_resource)
    # need to wait for all processes finish
    # {...}
    # Summarize resource
    do_something_with_resource(resource)
```

So basically I have 2 loops. I init process pool once outside the loops to avoid overheating. At the end of 2nd loop, I want to summarize the result of all processes.

Problem is that I can't use `pool.map()` to wait because of variation of `data` input. I can't use `pool.join()` and `pool.close()` either because I still need to use the `pool` in next iteration of 1st loop.

What is the good way to wait for processes to finish in this case?

I tried checking for pool._cache at the end of 2nd loop.

```
while len(process_pool._cache) > 0:
    sleep(0.001)
```

This way works but look weird. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`apply_async` will return an `AsyncResult` object. This object has a method `wait([timeout])`, you can use it.

Example:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
for i in range(300):
    results = []
    for m in range(500):
        data = do_some_calculation(resource)
        result = pool.apply_async(paralized_func, data, call_back=update_resource)
        results.append(result)
    [result.wait() for result in results]
    # need to wait for all processes finish
    # {...}
    # Summarize resource
    do_something_with_resource(resource)
```

I haven't checked this code as it is not executable, but it should work.

Comment: Yes. I thought of this. But I afraid it would consume a lot of memory when I accumulate the results in the array. In real code, the 2nd loop has big range.

Comment: You needn't to worry about it. First, the `AsyncResult` will be implicitly stored inside pool, so you won't save any space. Second, `AsyncResult` is just a very tiny object, it won't cost you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There's an issue with most upvoted answer

> `[result.wait() for result in results]`

will not work as a roadblock in case some of the workers raised an exception. Exception considered sufficient case to proceed further for wait(). Here's possible check if all workers finished processing.

```
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    # catch exception if results are not ready yet
    try:
        ready = [result.ready() for result in results]
        successful = [result.successful() for result in results]
    except Exception:
        continue
    # exit loop if all tasks returned success
    if all(successful):
        break
    # raise exception reporting exceptions received from workers
    if all(ready) and not all(successful):
        raise Exception(f'Workers raised following exceptions {[result._value for result in results if not result.successful()]}')
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use a callback to record how many returns you have got.

```py
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
for i in range(300):
    results = 0
    for m in range(500):
        data = do_some_calculation(resource)
        result = pool.apply_async(paralized_func, data, call_back=lambda x: results+=1; )
        results.append(result)
    
    # need to wait for all processes finish
    while results < 500:
        pass
    # Summarize resource
    do_something_with_resource(resource)
```